# Catch error thrown by constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling, constructor, try-catch

I have a class `foo` (that I can not modify) whit only one constructor that takes one argument like this:

```
foo bar("Hello!");
```

Since the constructor can throw an error, I want to implement error handling. My first attempt was this:

```
try {
    foo bar("Hello!");
}
catch {
    cerr << "Something went horribly wrong...";
    return -1;
}
```

However, now `foo` is within the scope of the `try` block and can not be used elsewhere. If I understand things right, I can not declare an object without initializing it, so I can declare `bar` outside of the `try` block. So what do I do to catch the error that the constructor throws?

*EDIT:* To clarify, this is in my `main`, and in the `catch` I will abort the program. Also, the argument is a file that will be opened, so there is no known safe input that will never raise an exception.

Comment: Put all the relevant code in the try block. Or in a function that you call in the try block.

Comment: With relevant code, do you mean code that uses the object? That would mean most of my program. Seems like a bit to much just to catch an error that might only occur during initialization?

Comment: Well, it is OK for most of your program to be contained in the `main()` function, right? So why not contain it in another function that you put in a try block?

Comment: If your whole programs relies on the `bar` object and it failed to construct, you do have a bit of an issue.

Comment: @MSalters Yes I do. So in that case I will abort the program. Sorry for being unclear about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is rather simple: the constructor failed, so the `bar` object was never created. C++ enforces this, and prevents you from using `bar` in that case.

You may solve this in another way:

```
foo makeFoo()
{
   try {
     return foo("Hello!"); // May throw
   }
   catch(...) {
     return foo("Safe"); // We know that "Safe" will not throw.
   }
}

bar foo{makeFoo()};
```

If you want to exit the program if the exception is thrown, you can print an error message and call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` inside the catch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm afraid there is no known input that is completely safe, since the parameter is a file that is to be read. And I think there is no `null` or something like that in C++ that I could return?

Comment: @Anders: Objects can't be `null`. Pointers can be `nullptr` though. And there's `boost::optional<foo>` which may or may not hold a `foo`. If your essential file is missing, you can of course print an error message and call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`  inside the catch.

Comment: Did not know about `exit`. That solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use heap allocation:

```
foo *p = 0;
try {
    p = new foo("parm");
} catch(const Error& err) {
    ...
}
foo& instance = *p;
// Here you can use instance normally...

delete p; // destroy before leaving scope (or use a smart pointer)
```

Comment: This gets you a null pointer dereference. Also, why not `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @MSalters: I assume that inside the `catch` body he'll solve the issue either allocating a working object or just aborting the program and not getting outside of the scope without a working object. With "or use a smart pointer" is exactly what I was thinking about...

Comment: This is in my `main`, and in the `catch` I will just print an error message and `return`.